# Equivalent of `poly.counts` to count lat/long pairs falling inside of polygons with the sf package

Tags: r, gis, r-sp, r-sf

The `sf` package provides a great approach to working with geographic features, but I can't figure out a simple equivalent to the `poly.counts` function from `GISTools` package which desires `sp` objects.

`poly.counts` computes the number of points from a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` fall within the polygons of a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and can be used as follows:

## Data

```
## Libraries
library("GISTools")
library("tidyverse")
library("sf")
library("sp")
library("rgdal")
## Obtain shapefiles
download.file(url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/STATE/tl_2016_us_state.zip", destfile = "data-raw/states.zip")
unzip(zipfile = "data-raw/states.zip", exdir = "data-raw/states")
sf_us_states <- read_sf("data-raw/states")

## Our observations:
observations_tibble <- tribble(
  ~lat, ~long,
31.968599,  -99.901813,
35.263266,  -80.854385,
35.149534,  -90.04898,
41.897547,  -84.037166,
34.596759,  -86.965563,
42.652579,  -73.756232,
43.670406,  -93.575858
)
```

## Calculate points per polygon

I generate both my `sp` objects:

```
sp_us_states <- as(sf_us_states, "Spatial")

observations_spdf <- observations_tibble %>%
  select(long, lat) %>% # SPDF want long, lat pairs
  SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = .,
                         data = .,
                         proj4string = sp_us_states@proj4string)
```

Now I can use `poly.counts`

```
points_in_states <-
  poly.counts(pts = observations_spdf, polys = sp_us_states)
```

Add this into the `sp` object:

```
sp_us_states$points.in.state <- points_in_states
```

Now I've finished I'd convert back to `sf` objects and could visualise as follows:

```
library("leaflet")
updated_sf <- st_as_sf(sp_us_states)
updated_sf %>%
  filter(points.in.state > 0) %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addPolygons() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(
    data = observations_tibble
  )
```

## Question

Can I perform this operation without tedious conversion between `sf` and `sp` objects?

Comment: take a look at the various options in `?sf::geos`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sf_obs = st_as_sf(observations_tibble, coords = c("long", "lat"), 
    crs = st_crs(sf_us_states))
lengths(st_covers(sf_us_states, sf_obs))
# check:
summary(points_in_states - lengths(st_covers(sf_us_states, sf_obs)))
```

`st_covers` returns a list with the indexes of points covered by each state; `lengths` returns the vector of the lenghts of these vectors, or the point count. The warnings you'll see indicate that although you have geographic coordinates, the underlying software assumes they are cartesian (which, for this case, will be most likely not problematic; move to projected coordinates if you want to get rid of it the proper way)

Comment: Ah, lovely! Thank you, I'm also appreciative of the warning message :)